# cakephp 'contain' left joint does not use specified foreignKey for left join

Tags: cakephp, join, foreign-key-relationship, contain

On cakephp 2.1, I have two tables: qca belongs to employee via field emp_number on both tables.

qca model belongsTo : (pleae note foreignKey)

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');

var $belongsTo = array('Dir', 
     'Employee' => array(
     'className' => 'Employee',
     'foreignKey' => 'emp_number')
 );
```

employee model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

On my controller's find, i use 'contain' to retrieve employee info based on emp_number from qca table.

```
$hoursvalues = $this->Qca->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions, 
            'fields' => array('Qca.emp_number', 'Sum(CASE WHEN Qca.qca_tipcode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Qca__comps', 'Sum(qca_end - qca_start) as Qca__production', 'Sum(Qca.qca_durend) as Qca__idle'),
            'contain' => array(
                'Employee' => array(
                    'fields' => array('emp_number', 'emp_ape_pat', 'emp_ape_mat', 'emp_ape_mat'))),
            'group' => array('Qca.emp_number'),
                ));
```

However, the executed sql sentence shows:

```
LEFT JOIN `devopm`.`employees` AS `Employee` ON (`Qca`.`emp_number` = `Employee`.`id`)
```

Whereas 
    `Employee`.`id` should be `Employee`.`emp_number`

This is the full sql sentence:

```
SELECT `Qca`.`emp_number`, Sum(CASE WHEN Qca.qca_tipcode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Qca__comps, Sum(qca_end - qca_start) as Qca__production, Sum(`Qca`.`qca_durend`) as Qca__idle, `Employee`.`emp_number`, `Employee`.`emp_ape_pat`, `Employee`.`emp_ape_mat`, `Employee`.`id` FROM `devopm`.`qcas` AS `Qca` LEFT JOIN `devopm`.`employees` AS `Employee` ON (`Qca`.`emp_number` = `Employee`.`id`) WHERE `Qca`.`dir_id` = 63 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`Qca`.`qca_start`, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2012-07-18' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`Qca`.`qca_start`, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2012-07-18' GROUP BY `Qca`.`emp_number`
```

This results on null values returned for Employee:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Qca' => array(
        'emp_number' => 'id3108',
        'comps' => '2',
        'production' => '7784',
        'idle' => '529'
    ),
    'Employee' => array(
        'emp_ape_pat' => null,
        'emp_ape_mat' => null,
        'id' => null
    )
),
```

Note: I have other instance of 'contain' working (one with default id = tableName.id). I'm wondering if the foreignKey on belongsTo ('foreignKey' => 'emp_number') is just not good for 'contain' to work?

Can you help?

Thank you so much.

(I found a workaround but slows down the query a great deal (it duplicates the left join and takes forever)

```
$joins = array(
 array('table' => 'publication_numerations',
   'alias' => 'PublicationNumeration',
   'type' => 'LEFT',
   'conditions' => array(
      'Publication.id = PublicationNumeration.publication_id',
   )
 )
);

$this->Publication->find('all', array('joins' => $joins));
```

Comment: try `$this->Qca->Employee->primaryKey = 'emp_number';` before your find

Comment: Great! it works, Thanks a lot! How could I have ever thought of that, I wonder. Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just have `Qca.employee_id`, though?

Comment: Main reason is that employees autoincrement id is not good for identifying employees; all employees have an id assigned already, which is being stored as emp_number. qca records belong to employees via emp_number.
Actually I was just about to write back because `$this->Qca->Employee->primaryKey = 'emp_number';` seems to take a lot of time and my server hangs up. Is it maybe that
the id is composite? e.g. 'id1520'
I'm considering tryng a) remove 'id' letters and use only numbers.
b) use employee.id as the employee identifier (change of strategy).
Thanks a lot.
Carlos

Comment: Shouldn't I somehow "reverse" `$this->Qca->Employee->primaryKey = 'emp_number';' after the find? Because it seems to run fine only the first time.